E2E Tests are getting failed (Error: Ended WebDriver sessions gracefully after a SIGINT signal was received)
When we (me and my team) are running multiple instances of e2e tests manually (or if they are running in multiple PR checks) we are facing this "Error: Ended WebDriver sessions gracefully after a SIGINT signal was received" and I have found that it only happens when there are multiple instances of e2e workflows running simultaneously (more than 10 instances at a time).
The version of wdio we are using is 8.10.2
Could you please help and tell what is the problem here. Also i am sharing the screenshots for you guys to have a look.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/8W8gUnTK.png)
We would like to understand the reason why this error comes up and how could we can prevent it.
We suspect comes when a large number of instances running simultaneously, So could you please confirm if there is any cap on number of e2e workflows that can be run at a time. If yes, how can we increase that number? Please share an example on how this can be configured.
FYI, Earlier the PR checks were passing even with this Error, (which is incorrect as gives the impression that our e2e ran without any issues).
here you can find a screenshot as reference. We would expect that as there’s SIGINT error displayed the workflow stops.
enter image description here
And to prevent that from happening we have added as workaround a command tracing to catch the error and make the check fail. Which is not ideal as this hide the logs until the e2e run is completed.
here you can see example of the workaround mentioned:
{
[# code ]

name: Running E2E tests
id: run-e2e
run: |
set -x  # Enable command tracing for debugging
[# some code executed here .....]
set +x  # Disable command tracing
if [[ "$OUTPUT" == "Ended WebDriver sessions gracefully after a SIGINT signal was received" ]]; then
echo "Webdriver error message detected; failing step."
exit 1
else
echo "No Webdriver error message found."
}


just to recap, we would like to know
Is there a version available where SIGINT error is handled properly and make the check fail
what is the limit of instances that can run at the same time without get the SIGINT error
thanks in advance for your attention, I highly appreciate your help on this.
